# Is conditional math mode tab autocompletion possible in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I'd like to define, say, a snippet that will

1. Tab autocomplete with `$$` to create a math mode expression if completion occurs **outside of** math mode, and
2. Autocomplete **without** the `$$` if completion occurs **within** math mode.

For example, I'd like to define a completion for `bb` such that

1) `bb` expands to `$\mathbb{ }$`

2) `$bb$` expands to `$\mathbb{ }$` and **not** `$$\mathbb{ }$$`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two files in your `Packages/User` directory (select `Preferences > Browse Packages...` and open the User folder)

`LaTeX.sublime-completions` with the content:

```js
{
    "scope": "text.tex.latex - meta.environment.math",

    "completions": [
        { "trigger": "bb\t\\\\mathbb{...}", "contents": "\\$\\\\mathbb{$1}\\$$0"},
        { "trigger": "bf\t\\\\mathbf{...}", "contents": "\\$\\\\mathbf{$1}\\$$0"}
    ]
}
```

`LaTeX math.sublime-completions` with the content:

```js
{
    "scope": "text.tex.latex meta.environment.math",

    "completions": [
        { "trigger": "bb\t\\\\mathbb{...}", "contents": "\\\\mathbb{$1}$0"},
        { "trigger": "bf\t\\\\mathbf{...}", "contents": "\\\\mathbf{$1}$0"}
    ]
}
```

Now you can add other commands in a similar style.